# Combinar com grid.arrange dois gráficos de resíduos (lme vs. lm)

Tags: r, modelagem, plot

Estou tentando colocar em uma mesma imagem, lado a lado, os gráficos dos resíduos ajustados pelo modelo linear e pelo modelo linear misto. No entanto, consultei os seguintes links abaixo e mesmo assim meu erro persiste:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34802295/control-layout-when-displaying-a-series-of-ggplot-plots-stored-in-a-list

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29121372/how-to-plot-multiple-lme-residual-plots-in-one-device

Como posso combinar esses gráficos em uma linha e duas colunas?

```
library(nlme)
Orthodont[c(1:20),]
data("Orthodont")

lm1 <- lm(distance ~ age, data=Orthodont)
fm1 <- lme(distance ~ age, Orthodont, random = ~ age | Subject)

p1=plot(fm1)
p2=plot(lm1$residuals)
myplots = list(p1,p2)

grid.arrange(grobs=myplots,ncol=2,top="Main Title", layout_matrix=cbind(c(1,2),c(3,4)))
do.call(grid.arrange, c(myplots,ncol=2,top="Main Title"))

> grid.arrange(grobs=myplots,ncol=2,top="Main Title", layout_matrix=cbind(c(1,2),c(3,4)))
Error in gList(list(p = list(formula = .y ~ .x, as.table = FALSE, aspect.fill = TRUE,  : 
  only 'grobs' allowed in "gList"
> do.call(grid.arrange, c(myplots,ncol=2,top="Main Title"))
Error in gList(list(p = list(formula = .y ~ .x, as.table = FALSE, aspect.fill = TRUE,  : 
  only 'grobs' allowed in "gList"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Antes de dar a minha resposta para a pergunta, gostaria de dizer que há uma série de problemas com essa análise de resíduos. Os gráficos criados sequer mostram a mesma informação. O gráfico para o modelo `lm1` mostra Resíduos padronizados versus Valores ajustados (que em geral não é utilizado nesse contexto específico), enquanto o gráfico para o modelo `fm1` mostra os Resíduos versus Posição no banco de dados (que é um gráfico que não faz sentido, pois a ordem dos resíduos não deveria ter influência na qualidade do ajuste realizado).

Além desse problema específico, normalmente são vários os gráficos utilizados para analisar os resíduos de um modelo linear, seja ele misto ou não. Abaixo mostro os quatros mais comuns para o modelo ajustado e salvo no objeto `lm1`.

```r
library(nlme)
library(ggfortify)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2

lm1 <- lm(distance ~ age, data=Orthodont)

autoplot(lm1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-11-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Note que há mais do que um gráfico sendo plotado simultaneamente. Em particular, o gráfico do canto superior direito é o que nos permite determinar se os resíduos seguem uma distribuição aproximadamente normal. Recomendo dar uma olhada em alguma referência de modelos lineares para saber o que cada um desses gráficos quer dizer (Kutner et al (2013), Applied Linear Statistical Models é um bom ponto de partida, embora pelo que eu me recorde ele não trate de modelos misto com muitos detalhes).

Isso posto, o problema aqui é a origem de cada um dos gráficos. O pacote `nlme` utiliza o pacote `lattice` para fazer gráficos do modelo `lm1`, enquanto o gráfico referente ao modelo `fm1` é feito com os gráficos padrão do R. Perceba como os estilos dos gráficos são bem diferentes entre si.

```r
library(nlme)

lm1 <- lm(distance ~ age, data=Orthodont)
fm1 <- lme(distance ~ age, Orthodont, random = ~ age | Subject)

plot(fm1)
```

[image]

```r
plot(lm1$residuals)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-11-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Sendo assim, minha sugestão é que ambos os gráficos sejam feitos no mesmo estilo, seja o padrão do R, `lattice` ou `ggplot2`. Por simplicidade, vou fazer ambos no `lattice`, usando para isso a função `xyplot` no caso do segundo gráfico.

Com os dois gráficos prontos, basta usar a função `grid.arrange` do pacote `gridExtra` para obter o resultado desejado.

```r
library(gridExtra)

p1 <- plot(fm1)
p2 <- xyplot(residuals ~ 1:length(lm1$residuals), lm1)

grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol = 2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-11-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Obrigado @Marcus Nunes!!!